# Pandas DataFrame combine multi row spanning column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, pdf-scraping

I have a complex scraped dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

For context, the original data from a PDF looks like so:

[image]

DataFrame info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 26 entries, 0 to 25
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   0       26 non-null     object
 1   1       26 non-null     object
 2   2       26 non-null     object
 3   3       26 non-null     object
 4   4       26 non-null     object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 1.1+ KB
```

I want the data to look like image below. Every row with `S` or `P` in column `1` (`Transaction Type`) should join column `0` (`Asset`) rows together until next `S` or `P` occurs in column `1`:
[image]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

## below code gives you every column 1 where row is not None (meaning it has an S or P) other part of your q i cannot understand.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
dfs = df['0'][(df['1']=="S")]
dff = df['0'][(df['1']=="P")]
print("Sdays", " ".join(dfs))
print("Fdays", " ".join(dff))

I think now its ok.
```

Comment: I have added image to clarify.